# Angular 2 url construction with '@' symbol

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

How do I add '@' symbol while constructing routes

like `localhost/@user`

I tried

```
{
    path:'\@:username',
    component:ProfileComponent
}
```

and

```
{
    path:"'\@':username",
    component:ProfileComponent
}
```

no success

I should Only get the Username as param,
one possible solution is I can do this

```
{
    path:':username',
    component:ProfileComponent
}
```

and remove '@' in the ": param ,use param,
Is there any way I can get the first one working?

Comment: for now, you can't use a regex in routes definition. So, unfortunately, you'll have to get the param in your component and remove the @

Comment: @madhu-kumar - did you figure out how to do it?

Comment: I am currently doing with regex and split. It works for now. Will keep trying

Answer (score 0):

You could try to implement custom `UrlSerializer` and localize `@:` replacement there.

See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/UrlSerializer-class.html